# Convert ArrayCollection into ArrayLIst in Flex 4.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am using Flex SDK 4.5 and I want to Convert ArrayCollection to ArrayList to populate ComboBox. How Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
new ArrayList(yourArrayCollectionObject as Array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need such a conversion?

Can't you use the ArrayCollection as dataProvider for the ComboBox?

Comment: in 4.5 it accept arrayList rather than arrayCollection. however in flex 3 and 3.5, we can provide arrayCollection as dataProvider.